Rolling a die twice and summing the outcomes
Hi I am trying to get this code to produce the following outcome:
2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 9   5  6  7  8  9 10  6  7  8  9 10 11 7  8  9 10 11 12
as one output. Right now it is all separate. Or I want outcome1= 2,3,4,5,6,7 and outcome2=3,4,5,6,7,8....
dice = c(1:6)
for (i in 1:length(dice)){
outcomes(i) <-  dice[i]+c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
print(outcomes(i))
}

I can't get the outcome to work so outcomes1=2,3,4,5,6 and outcomes2=3,4,5,6,7,7
Thank you
Kelly

You want that list of numbers summed? Or you want them listed together as a single string?

What exactly do you mean "as one output"? Are you trying to create a 6x6 matrix of values? Or do you want a list of vectors? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here exactly.

I don't see any rolling of dice going on here. How does what you're doing relate to the title of your question? How is this a simulation of anything other what do I get when I do deterministic arithmetic?

You can use embed or outer
setNames(asplit(embed(2:12, 6)[, 6:1], 1), paste0("outcome", 1:6))

or
setNames(asplit(outer(dice, dice, `+`), 1), paste0("outcome", 1:6))

which gives
$outcome1
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

$outcome2
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8

$outcome3
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$outcome4
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

$outcome5
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11

$outcome6
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12


If you want to have them as global variables, you can use list2env
res <- setNames(asplit(embed(2:12, 6)[, 6:1], 1), paste0("outcome", 1:6))
# res <- setNames(asplit(outer(dice, dice, `+`), 1), paste0("outcome", 1:6))

list2env(res, globalenv())


This above code doesn't work because when I call outcome1 or outcome 2 on a separate prompt it doesn't have the information stored in R.

The code works just fine. You have to assign the outcomes like my_list <- setNames(asplit(embed(2:12, 6)[, 6:1], 1), paste0("outcome", 1:6)). Then use my_list$outcome1 etc.

@KellyF see my update

Consider
dice = 1L:6L
setNames(lapply(seq_along(dice), \(i) dice[i] + dice), paste0("outcome", dice))

giving
$outcome1
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

$outcome2
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8

$outcome3
[1] 4 5 6 7 8 9

$outcome4
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

$outcome5
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11

$outcome6
[1]  7  8  9 10 11 12

and
do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(dice), \(i) dice[i] + dice))

giving
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  3  4  5  6  7  8  4  5  6  7  8  9  5  6  7  8  9
[24] 10  6  7  8  9 10 11  7  8  9 10 11 12


I would also like this to output as one list or vector of numbers.

I could not get the above suggested code did not work.

Basically I can't get the outcome{i} to read outcomes1, outcomes2, outcomes6
dice = c(1:6)
for (i in 1:length(dice)){
outcomes(i) <-  dice[i]+c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
print(outcomes(i))
}
